# How to create Django model from json response

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a Django app which show some btc prices that I get then from a external API, my problem comes when the app is gonna load, It need to always make a call to the API to show me data. So it takes very long time for the app to load or even when I want to make some changes on the website the app needs to make a call to the API wait for the response, So after that it can show me a data, My goal at this time it will be to save that json response into a Django model so the app wouldn't have to be calling the API all the time so the website will load faster.
So my questions is which one it will be the best way to archive that?
or how can I even try to do that?

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("index")
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    context = {
        "task_form": form, 
        "tasks": tasks, 
        "precio_uk": get_price_uk(),
        "average_uk": get_average_price_uk(),
        "precio_ves": get_price_ves(),
        "average_ves": get_average_price_ves(),
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name="index"),
    path("update/<int:pk>", views.update_task, name="update_task"),
    path("deleted/<int:pk>/", views.delete_task, name="delete_task"),
    path('multi',views.multiplication, name='multi'),

]
```

Models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title=models.IntegerField()
    completed=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: With a serializer: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

Comment: Either the question title should be "how to create Django object from JSON", or you're asking us to design schema for you?